# Fetching User with First and Lastname Query Search

Tags: php, search

People can search like "Jonathan Steve"

If i type only Jonathan, i get the result. But if i type Jonathan Steve there is no answer from php

Database:
user_first | user_last
Jonathan     Steve

The user should type in one input "Jonathan Steve" and should get the result

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once("../config.php");
require_once("../inc/function.php");    

$query = htmlspecialchars($mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['q']));

$query = explode(" ", $query);

foreach($query as $search)
{
    $searching = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE LOWER(user_first) LIKE LOWER('%$search%') OR LOWER(user_last) LIKE LOWER('%$search%') OR LOWER(user_uname) LIKE LOWER('%$search%')");
    echo "<h5 style=\"padding-left: 5px;\">Personen</h5>";
    while($result = $searching->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $name = $result['user_first']." ".$result['user_last'];
        $uname = $result['user_uname'];
        $image = $result['user_img'];
        $fid = $result['user_id'];

        if(empty($image))
        {
            $image = "nop.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            $image = "$fid/profileimages/$image";   
        }
        echo "<div class='search-user'><a href='profile.php?p=$uname'><div style='background: url(_usr/$image) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover' class='imgdiv'></div><span>$name</span></a></div>";
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: you need to include the rest of your code this is only a snippet, second you will be open to SQL Injections once you turn your query into a form input, and lastly you should look into `MATCH(user_first, user_last, user_uname) AGAINST (:search)` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: During development, at the beginning of the code, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see any errors that occur. I think that your attempt to call `$mysqli->query()` throws an error that makes the script execution abort.

Comment: So i added error reporting and i get no error. I updated this post, hope now everyone can understand it

Answer (score 0):

If "Jonathan Steve" is a first and last name, your code is trying to match it to `user_first` OR `user_last`, but not both together. There's nothing in `user_first` that matches "Jonathan Steve" and the same applies to `user_last`.

Try this instead:

```
$searching = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE 
    LOWER(concat_ws(' ', user_first, user_last, user_uname)) LIKE LOWER('%$search%')");
```

Answer (score -1):

from what i can tell the below code is what you want.
Instead of searching for "Mark" OR "Phillips", you should search for "Mark" & "Phillips".

What if there are two users called "Mark", it would match the first user even if that wasnt me.

Give it a go, totally untested, i hope it helps somewhat.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once("../config.php");
    require_once("../inc/function.php");    

    //First "explode" their name
    $personsFullName = strtolower(htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']));
    $personsNameExplosion = explode(" ", $personsFullName);
    $firstName = null;

    //If the explosion contains multiple elements, sort it into seperate variables for code-reading value
    if ( sizeof($personsnameExplosion) > 1 )
    {
        $firstName = $personsNameExplosion[0];
        $secondName = $personsNameExplosion[1];
    }

    //Start to build the query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user_tbl WHERE ";

    //If we set $firstName, change the query.
    if ( $firstName != null )
        $query .= "LOWER(user_first) LIKE '%$firstName%' AND LOWER(user_last) LIKE '%$secondName%'"
    else
        $query = "LOWER(user_first) LIKE '%$personsFullName%' OR LOWER(user_last) LIKE '%$personsFullName%' OR LOWER(user_uname) LIKE '%$personsFullName%'"

    //Run the query:
    //Note: Please learn about MySQLi bindings to prevent SQL injection.
    $queryResult = $mysqli->query($query);
    echo "<h5 style=\"padding-left: 5px;\">Personen</h5>";
    while($result = $queryResult->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $name = $result['user_first']." ".$result['user_last'];
        $uname = $result['user_uname'];
        $image = $result['user_img'];
        $fid = $result['user_id'];

        if(empty($image))
        {
            $image = "nop.jpg";
        }
        else
        {
            $image = "$fid/profileimages/$image";   
        }
        echo "<div class='search-user'><a href='profile.php?p=$uname'><div style='background: url(_usr/$image) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover' class='imgdiv'></div><span>$name</span></a></div>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thats works fine, but if i type "Mark Phillips" in the input it dont show a result

Comment: I want to make a search like facebooks. So u can type "Mark" and your are in the results and also "Mark Phillips"